# How can I import modules only if they exist?

Tags: rust, conditional-compilation

I am doing advent of code, which is a collection of 25 programming problems, one for each of day of the advent.

I structure each day in it's own separate file/module, so for example year 2021 day 7 would be at `src/years/year2021/day07.rs`. So `src/years/year2021/mod.rs` ends up being just `pub mod`s

```
pub mod day01;
pub mod day02;
pub mod day04;
// and so on...
```

Is there a way I could generate this list dynamically (with something like a recursive macro), so check if module day01 is accessible from this context (or alternatively if ./day01.rs exists) and generate the `pub mod` automatically, and add more as files are created.

The best would be the ability to check if any name exists, like a module or a function inside a module.

Comment: I would suggest giving the organization here a try: [How should I structure a Rust project for solving small coding challenges?](/q/73738228/2189130) Structuring it that way will only require one source file per day and doesn't require any intermediate boilerplate like imports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [build.rs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) to generate a module based on the files that exist at build time.

Something like this possably

```
let years_path = path::Path::new("./src/years");
let mut mod_file = fs::File::create(years_path.join("mod.rs")).unwrap();

let paths = fs::read_dir(years_path).unwrap();

for entry in paths {
    let entry = entry.unwrap();
    if entry.metadata().unwrap().is_dir() {
        writeln!(
            mod_file,
            "mod {};",
            entry.path().file_name().unwrap().to_str().unwrap()
        )
        .unwrap();
    }
}
```

Comment: Accepted this as an answer, but instead of generating rs files in the src directory I put them in OUT_DIR with the filename based on the module, then in the mod.rs' inside src/ I include!() based on module_path!() plus a suffix. That way these autogenerated "headers" don't pollute the git commits

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a version of `build.rs` quite similar to @pidgeonhands one.
It's a bit more resilient (it only crashes when it can't create or write to the files) to weird files inside the folders and does work for multiple years:

```rust
use std::{
    error::Error,
    ffi::OsString,
    fs::{self, File},
    io::Write,
    path::Path,
};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=src/years");
    let years_path = Path::new("src/years");
    let mut years_mod_file = File::create(years_path.join("mod.rs"))?;
    for year in fs::read_dir("src/years")? {
        let Ok(year) = year else {continue};
        let year_name = year.file_name();
        let Some(year_name) = year_name.to_str() else {continue};
        if year_name != OsString::from("mod.rs") {
            writeln!(years_mod_file, "pub mod {year_name};")?;
            let mut year_mod_file = File::create(year.path().join("mod.rs"))?;

            for day in fs::read_dir(year.path())? {
                let Ok(day) = day else {continue};
                if day.file_name() != OsString::from("mod.rs") {
                    let day_name = day.path();
                    let Some(day_name) = day_name.file_stem() else {continue};
                    let Some(day_name) = day_name.to_str() else {continue};
                    writeln!(year_mod_file, "pub mod {day_name};")?;
                    println!("{:?}", day_name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```